# What is the use of Vertica "metadata" resource pool?

Tags: vertica

In Vertica 8, the "metadata" resource pool was introduced. [The documentation describes it as](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/Built-inPools.htm#METADATA) :

> The pool that tracks memory allocated for catalog data and storage data structures.

It doesn't seem essential, since the documentation indicates how to disable it using the EnableMetadataMemoryTracking parameter.

What is this pool used for ? Since it consumes quite a lot of RAM (4Gb on our servers), can I disable it safely ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

metadata RAM it's vertica catalog size, reserved dynamically RAM that vertica process allocated for catalog.

for example you have 32GB of RAM total , vertica will use 95% of total ram ~30.5 GB but you have large catalog ~3GB (tons of objects) and vertica process consume couple of GB -> vertica process uses RAM that according to general pool must be free for queries -> can cause starvation.

If you use metadata pool that dynamicly borrow from general RAM needed for catalog your resource management will be better.

BTW why you have 4GB RAM catalog?? its kinda huge how much RAM vertica process consume in IDLE? Is it consume less after restart and grows over time?

created simple script that create 1000 tables with 100 int columns, insert 1 row and analyze statistics. You can see how catalog size grow with number of objects and how it affect metadata pool and vertica process RAM :

```
dbadmin=> select (select count(1) from tables),node_name,memory_size_kb,memory_size_actual_kb from resource_pool_status where pool_name ilike 'metadata';
 ?column? |      node_name       | memory_size_kb | memory_size_actual_kb
----------+--------------------+----------------+-----------------------
      218 | v_vertica_node0001 |         108622 |                108622
      218 | v_vertica_node0002 |         119596 |                119596
      218 | v_vertica_node0003 |         122374 |                122374
(3 rows)

dbadmin=> select (select count(1) from tables),node_name,memory_size_kb,memory_size_actual_kb from resource_pool_status where pool_name ilike 'metadata'; \! top -n 1  | grep vertica
 ?column? |      node_name       | memory_size_kb | memory_size_actual_kb
----------+--------------------+----------------+-----------------------
      513 | v_vertica_node0001 |         229210 |                229210
      513 | v_vertica_node0002 |         281601 |                281601
      513 | v_vertica_node0003 |         289407 |                289407
(3 rows)

476260 dbadmin   20   0 5391m 407m  39m S 109.2  2.6  21:25.64 vertica
dbadmin=> select (select count(1) from tables),node_name,memory_size_kb,memory_size_actual_kb from resource_pool_status where pool_name ilike 'metadata'; \! top -n 1  | grep vertica
 ?column? |      node_name       | memory_size_kb | memory_size_actual_kb
----------+--------------------+----------------+-----------------------
      825 | v_vertica_node0001 |         352359 |                352359
      825 | v_vertica_node0002 |         448032 |                448032
      825 | v_vertica_node0003 |         456439 |                456439
(3 rows)

476260 dbadmin   20   0 5564m 554m  39m S 79.2  3.5  38:16.91 vertica
dbadmin=> select (select count(1) from tables),node_name,memory_size_kb,memory_size_actual_kb from resource_pool_status where pool_name ilike 'metadata'; \! top -n 1  | grep vertica
 ?column? |      node_name       | memory_size_kb | memory_size_actual_kb
----------+--------------------+----------------+-----------------------
     1143 | v_vertica_node0001 |         489867 |                489867
     1143 | v_vertica_node0002 |         627409 |                627409
     1143 | v_vertica_node0003 |         635616 |                635616
(3 rows)

476260 dbadmin   20   0 5692m 711m  39m S  0.7  4.5  58:13.61 vertica
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer.
The database contains 170 tables for a total of 18 000 columns, mainly varchar(5000) columns. I guess this is the source of the huge catalog size problem.

Comment: FYI, after a node restart, the metadata pool memory dropped from 4 Gb to 740Mb.